# OLAP cubes processing in IE10 and windows server 2012

Tags: olap, internet-explorer-10

I have been using OLAP cubes successfully with windows OWC components for IE6-IE9 and Windows XP- Windows 7 with sql server 2005/2008. I have not encountered any issues till then.
But when I try to run my application on Windows Server 2012 with IE 10 browser with sql server 2005/2008, the cubes doesn't render. It doesn't give any error message either. The page just doesn't load cubes. All the other functionality works fine apart from that. Again if you run IE in IE8 compatibility mode it works fine, but if you change the compatibility mode to IE9/IE10 the cubes doesn't show up at all. No error on page. 
My IE security settings are intact. Not sure if I need to download another piece of software or any other component for the cubes to work.
Any help would be great since I am stuck since 2 days at that point.
Thanks,
Nihir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the issue was with the vbscript function called. It seems IE10 expects vbscript funciton to be either in all lower cases or all upper cases. No mixed case mode is allowed. changing function name to all lower cases worked fine